Unmarshal a json array with eclipse link
I'm trying to unmarshal a json array in a dynamic object using eclipselink moxy and JSON metatdata model.
Here's my Json metadata model
{
   "package-name" : "com.deep.eclipse.link",
   "xml-schema" : {
      "element-form-default" : "QUALIFIED",
      "namespace" : "http://www.com.deep.eclipse.link/data"
   },
   "java-types" : {
      "java-type" : [ {
         "name" : "Data",
         "xml-type" : {
            "prop-order" : "releves"
         }, 
         "xml-root-element" : {},
         "java-attributes" : {
            "xml-element" : [
                {"java-attribute" : "releves", "name" : "releves" , "type" :"com.deep.eclipse.link.Releves", "container-type":"java.util.Collections"}
            ]
         }
      },{
         "name" : "Releves",
         "java-attributes" : {
            "xml-element" : [ 
                {"java-attribute" : "name", "xml-path" : "name/text()"},
                {"java-attribute" : "date", "xml-path" : "date/text()"},
                {"java-attribute" : "data", "xml-path" : "data/text()"}
            ]
         }
      }  ]
   }
}

This is the input JSON input file
{ 
    "releves": [ 
        {
            "name": "aaa",
            "date": "2015-07-11",
            "data": "dddAXsxOkYwMUZTQktEWkFMQVhYWDAwMDAwMDAwMDB9ezI"
        },
        {
            "name": "bbb",
            "date": "2015-07-12",
            "data": "eeAXsxOkYwMUZTQktEWkFMQVhYWDAwMDAwMDAwMDB9ezI"
        }
    ]
}

I want to convert this input file to a dynamic object and i'm only half successful. I get the dynamic Object Releves but I have only the second set of data containing  "name":"bbb". What I want to achieve is an Array/List containing both blocs.
Dynamic Object Created
Here' my code
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE,"application/json");
properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "src/main/resources/bank.statements.json");
properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME, true);
ClassLoader myClassLoader =  Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        
DynamicJAXBContext jc = DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromOXM(myClassLoader, properties);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
unmarshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, true);
Class releves = jc.newDynamicEntity("com.deep.eclipse.link.Releves").getClass();
JAXBElement<DynamicEntity> element = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new File("src/main/resources/input.bank.statement.json")), releves);
System.out.println(element.getValue());

Thanks in advance for your help

I made some changes and it's working fine. Here is the code
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE,"application/json");
properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "src/main/resources/bank.statements.json");
ClassLoader myClassLoader =  Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
DynamicJAXBContext jc = DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromOXM(myClassLoader, properties);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
unmarshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
Class statement = jc.newDynamicEntity("com.deep.eclipse.link.Statement").getClass();
JAXBElement<DynamicEntity> element = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new File("src/main/resources/input.bank.statement.json")), statement);

And the OXM metadata file
{
   "package-name" : "com.deep.eclipse.link",
   "xml-schema" : {
      "element-form-default" : "QUALIFIED",
      "namespace" : "http://www.com.deep.eclipse.link/statement"
   },
   "java-types" : {
      "java-type" : [ {
         "name" : "Statement",
         "xml-type" : {
            "prop-order" : "datas"
         }, 
         "java-attributes" : {
            "xml-element" : [
                {"java-attribute" : "datas" , "name": "releves", "type" :"com.deep.eclipse.link.Data","container-type":"java.util.List"}
            ]
         }
      },{
         "name" : "Data",
         "java-attributes" : {
            "xml-element" : [ 
                {"java-attribute" : "name", "xml-path" : "name/text()"},
                {"java-attribute" : "date", "xml-path" : "date/text()"},
                {"java-attribute" : "data", "xml-path" : "data/text()"}
            ]
         }
      }]
   }
}

Now I get a dynamic object containing an ArrayList with two entries inside.
Thanks!

Thanks for answering your own question. Please spell out in text explanation what the changes are so readers don’t have to run diff on each of the code snippets to see what is going on.
